# Google App Scripts - If script is written directly to spreadsheet, why would Spreadsheet.app fail to access itself?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Newbie here looking to make an online visualization tool for clients I serve. Currently, my script is working with a 0.02% error rate; These errors are caused by what seems to be a permission issue. The head-scratcher for me is the ID of the spreadsheet listed in the error log is the same spreadsheet that the script is bound to - what would cause this?

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgJe6.png)

I've tried throwing a spreadsheetapp.flushe(); into the program to let it finish executing before moving on to the next script but the problem has yet to disappear

Comment: I would suggest you post the code causing the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.